# How to access to MULE_HOME variable from a file properties?

Tags: mule, environment-variables, properties-file

I want access to the MULE_HOME varabile from a file properties , i already used `muleEnv=${MULE_HOME}` but it dosen't worked .

Answer (score 1):

Mule Home can be accessed using MEL expression:- `#[mule.home]` in the flow
You can put this expression in a properties file as follows:-

```
muleEnv=#[mule.home]
```

and can access in the flow:-

```
<logger level="INFO" message="## Mule home: ${muleEnv}" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

simple and easy :)

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's Not simple and not easy as you say , it dosen't work.
I want to access to mule.home from the server and not from the application using a key=value in mule-deploy.properties

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with server?  Are you referring to the Mule Runtime or the computer where the Mule Runtime is running ?

you can try to initialise your mule runtime with -M-Dmule.home.dir=%MULE_HOME%.

In this the case the runtime will contain the MULE_HOME directory and you it should be avaible with ${mule.home.dir}

This is not necessary at all, when a mule runtime is initialised, you should have a property mule.home  with the value of the MULE_HOME variable, try to change ${MULE_HOME} for ${mule.home}  or ${mule.base}

This is working for me:

test.properties -->  test.var.home=${mule.home}

in my flow:

```
 <logger message="${test.var.home}" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: @7533972 , i mean the mule runtime , i already initialise my mule runtime with -M-Dmule.home=%MULE_HOME%. , when i try to access to this property via mule-deploy.properties he consider $MULE_HOME as a String and not as a property.
i dont want to access to this property via logger or something , i want to access via mule-deploy.properties